# Android.bat can't run java

Tags: java, android, eclipse, windows

I know this question has been beaten to death but I still cannot get the SDK Manager to run on my Windows 7 Home.

I downloaded the eclipse + adt bundle. The SDK Manager.exe is in the sdk folder where I try to run it from. I even tried copying it to the tools folder and tried running from there but no luck.

The error I get is:

```
Failed to execute tools\android.bat:
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The file clearly exists. I tried running it as "Administrator" as well.

Next I tried running the android.bat file itself which says:

```
Windows cannot find 'E:\path\to\batfile'. 
Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.
```

I then ran it as "Administrator" which at least detects and tries to execute it. I added in a few pause statements to android.bat itself to prevent it from closing.

Here is what I see:

```
'"E:\ADT\sdk\tools\lib\\find_java.exe" -s' is not recognized as an internal
or external command, operable program or batch file.

ERROR: No suitable Java found. In order to properly use the Android Developer
Tools, you need a suitable version of Java JDK installed on your system.
We recommend that you install the JDK version of JavaSE, available here:
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads

If you already have Java installed, you can define the JAVA_HOME environment
variable in Control Panel / System / Avanced System Settings to point to the
JDK folder.
```

Not sure why it says that because when I run where java in cmd I get this:

```
C:\Users\(MyUser)>where java
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java.exe
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\Windows\System32\java.exe
```

And when I open cmd and manually run

```
'"E:\ADT\sdk\tools\lib\\find_java.exe" -s'
```

it works fine.

I then tried setting the java_exe in android.bat to

```
set java_exe=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java.exe
```

After commenting out the find_java I ran it again and this is what I get:

```
'"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java.exe" -jar lib\archquery.jar' is not
 recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Invalid path
```

And once again, when I manually run it, I get:

```
C:\Users\MyUser>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java.exe" -jar E:\ADT\sdk\t
ools\lib\archquery.jar
x86_64
```

Am I missing something or should I finally give up trying to get it to work on my windows machine.

Comment: out of curiosity. DO you have the JAVA_HOME set and pointing to the main sdk directory? (not the bin, the one above)

Comment: yes, it's set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05

Answer (score 0):

Your `where java` shows too many `java.exe`, the `find_java.bat` will try to look for `javaw` as well in  the folder where `java` is.

set JAVA_HOME and make sure the `echo %PATH%` points to your main jdk installation.

Comment: I've set JAVA_HOME to  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05 and my PATH also contains it. As you can see, the order of where java shows it at the top as well.

Comment: @Joiya550 `find_java.exe` may be picking up the other ones. When you manully set the java, can you try enclosing the full path in quotes.

Comment: Also tried that, and when I ran find_java.exe myself using the cmd, it got the first one i.e the java jdk 8 one. Plus I removed the Oracle java as well

Comment: I believe the problem is that it cannot even run the find_java.exe as it says command unrecognized.

Comment: @Joiya550 can you try adding the `<sdk-path>\tools` to your path

Comment: Ok I added it,   C:\Users\MyUser>echo %PATH%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin;E:\ADT\sdk\tools;  Still the same issue

Comment: I have 64 bit java, could it be an issue?

Comment: @Joiya550 yes! [please download the x64 SDK+ADT](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#win-bundle)

Comment: Ah sorry, my statement was confusing. I'm actually using the x64 SDK+ADT and thought that maybe it was the reason. (Also running Windows 7 64 bit)